# Reading a file and using each line as variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, variables

I know that I can read a file (file.txt) then using each line as part of a variable.

```
f = open( "file.txt", "r" )
for line in f:
    sentence = "The line is: " + line
    print (sentence)
f.close()
```

However, let's say that I have a file that has the following lines:

```
joe 123
mary 321
dave 432
```

In bash I can do something like:

```
cat file.txt | while read name value
do
 echo "The name is $name and the value is $value"
done
```

How can I do that with Python? In other words, each "word" within each line read them as variables?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `"joe 123".split()` is a list `["joe", "123"]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pythonic equivalent could be:

```
with open( "file.txt", "r" ) as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.split()
        print(f'The name is {name} and the value is {value}')
```

This uses:

- a context manager (the `with` statement) for automatically closing the file once you're done
- tuple/list unpacking to assign `name` and `value` from the list returned from `.split()`
- the new `f` string syntax which features variable interpolation. (use `str.format` for older python versions)

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open( "file.txt", "r" )
for line in f:
    values = line.split()
    sentence = "The name is " + values[0] + " and the value is " + values[1]
    print (sentence)
f.close()
```

Comment: Could you explain the OP why that is the answer to his question?

Comment: He has input in file like this `joe 123 \n mary 321 \n dave 432`, we read that file and iterate line by line and then split each line, so values[0] will have name and values[1] will have number then print accordingly. I hope this answer your query,